# SvelteKit async load not awaiting sort

Tags: async-await, svelte, sveltekit

```js
// $lib/types.ts
export type GlobResults = Record<string, ()=>Promise<unknown>>

// $lib/utils.ts
export const LoadGlobsOneByOne = async (globs: GlobResults) => {
    let results = []
    for (const path in globs) {
        let data = await globs[path]()
        results.push(data)
    }
    return results
}

export const LoadGlobsAllAtOnces = async (globs: GlobResults) => {
    let results = await Promise.all(Object.values(globs).map(fn=>fn()))
    return results
}

// $lib/routes/members/+page.ts
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
import type {Members} from '$lib/types'
import {LoadGlobsAllAtOnces, SortMemberByImage} from '$lib/utils'

// NOTE: originally had it as a single JSON
//       now each member is in a separate YML file.
// import members from '$lib/data/members.json'
const yamls = import.meta.glob(
    '/src/yaml/members/*.yml', 
    {import: 'default'}
)

export async function load({ }) {   
    let members = (await LoadGlobsAllAtOnces(yamls) as Members)
        .sort(SortMemberByImage)
        
    return { members };
  }
```

No matter what I try I get all of the yamls in the order they are named in under `/src/yamls/members/*1` instead of the sort order. I have tried wrapping the sort in another async function and awaiting that. I have tried in the `+page.svelte` waiting with an async block, as well as declaration to a `$: sorted = ...`. How do I wait or enforce that the results are returned once sorted?

Comment: Are you positive your sort function actually works? Could you add its code to your question? A sample of the data being loaded would be nice as well (especially the part containing the sorting criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
 let members = await LoadGlobsAllAtOnces(yamls) as Members
 let sortedMembers = members.sort(SortMemberByImage)
 return { sortedMembers };
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.I also tried wrapping that in an async / await function and awaiting that as well

Comment: @SumNeuron, how about `Promise.all`? does it work?

Comment: If you look at my example I am using promise all